# Why is a global `name` variable declared in typescript and can I avoid using it?

Tags: node.js, typescript

A friend refactored some code and moved the definition of a variable called `name` from the function's top-level scope into a `then`'s body. This variable was used in a subsequent `then` which caused a **ReferenceError** since `name` was not in scope.

We couldn't understand how the code passed compilation until we saw that [typescript/lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) has the following deceleration:

```
declare const name: never;
```

Long story short, I have two questions.

1. Why is `name` (as well as `length` and many other globals) added by default to typescript?
2. From the surrounding code this seems meant for projects intended to run in a browser, we're a node.js project. Can we opt out from having these declarations added for us?

Comment: For whatever reasons, they are on the global `window` object o.O Open your DevTools and enter `name` (will result in the empty string `""`) or `length` (will return `3`). This may vary depending on the browser you're using. Can you show some code? Maybe there is a issue with your usage/initialization of `name`?

Comment: @SebastianSebald as I said, we're not using a browser, we're using Node which doesn't have these properties on the global object. Doesn't typescript have a non-browser mode?

Comment: Updated my answer :) I missed that part of your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a very old browser behaviour. Referring to the MDN both `name` and `length` are properties of the `window` object.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length

In order to get rid of all the DOM-specific declarations, you can set the `lib` property in your `tsconfig` accordingly. You cann see all options on [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Take a look at the `--lib` flag.

An option to tell TypeScript your code runs on Node.JS would be nice. But it seems not yet implemented: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9466

Comment: Just be careful because you can accidentally attempt to overwrite the globals now. Instead of `declare var` you can use `var` and the typechecker will let you assign to them.